# iis the directory name is invalid

Tags: iis, c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net project with mvc5 that uses filesystem watcher to monitor a directory which is a shared folder by a server. So the path would be starting with  a double backslash \\

Running the project out of visual studio works fine. When deploying the project to my virtualized windows server 2016 and browsing localhost gets me a server error where the Diretory name \\path\to\remote\folder is invalid.

Opening that path with the file explorer didn't bring up any error at all.
My guess is that there might be a switch somehwere in the configuration of IIS that I'm not aware about nor what that terminology is called.

Let me know if you need any configuration files to be posted.

This is also my first time working in the Microsoft Server enviroment, I come from the Linux side.

So if anyone has good source of how to work and configure IIS, I would highly appreciate it if you can point them out to me.

Comment: Does IIS user account  have access to this share?

Comment: If it didn't have access to that share then the message would say something like: Insuficient rights to access this directory.
Is there a way how to validate that?

Comment: Error messages could be misleading. It would be nice if you show us an exact message or a screenshot.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HXU5tGX.png

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219373/filesystemwatcher-to-watch-unc-path ?

Comment: Tried that out but didn't really help.

Comment: I believe you should try some googling. There's a lot of results regarding this error, try them before and then get back here if none work.

Comment: Maybe [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/q/799385/210623might) might be worth a look?